# UITableViewCell contentView Label at Index

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, uilabel

I have an UITableViewCell and I add a subView to a label.

```
[cell addSubview:stateLabel];
```

I want to change the label when the user presses a cell.

```
[tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
```

This gives me the pressed indexPath, but can anyone help me **how** to change the label at that position where the user pressed?

I think I just need a hint and then I can do the rest by myself...

For example, if the user presses cell 8, it changes the stateLabelsubview of cell 8.

This is what I've got so far:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellID";

    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        stateLabel = [ [UILabel alloc ] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(240,0,100,44)];
        stateLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
        stateLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        stateLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial Rounded MT Bold" size:(13.0)];
        stateLabel.text = @"Not applied";
        [cell addSubview:stateLabel];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [cheatNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


    return cell;

}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSIndexPath *selectedRowPath = [tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];


}
```

Thanks!

Comment: no need for a full reload! IMHO

Answer (score 1):

you can implement something like this

in your `cellForRowatIndexPath:` Method before the return cell;

get the `indexpath` of the selected row for changing the label. 
and use

```
if(indexpath == selected index)
{
    // do ur code here

}
```

as soon as `didSelectRow:` is called reload the table

this will defintely work.

Answer (score 0):

no reload required IMHO:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSIndexPath *selectedRowPath = [tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    myString = @"Any Data";
    [tableView reloadData];

    UITableCellView *cell = [tableView cellAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.label.title = myString;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Define `myString` in the .h file as an `NSString`

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

NSIndexPath *selectedRowPath = [tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
myString = @"Any Data";
[tableView reloadData];

}
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellID";

cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    stateLabel = [ [UILabel alloc ] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(240,0,100,44)];
    stateLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
    stateLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    stateLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial Rounded MT Bold" size:(13.0)];
    stateLabel.text = myString;
    [cell addSubview:stateLabel];
}

cell.textLabel.text = [cheatNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


return cell;

}
```

Comment: I want to change a LABEL, not the celltext. Changing the celltext is easy, because you habe the selected cell, but changing the subview Label of that cell is what I need